# How to suppress Alamofire output to debug console in Xcode

Tags: alamofire

Simplest Alamofire sample. main.swift:

```
import Alamofire
import Foundation

AF.request("https://httpbin.org/get").response { response in
    // debugPrint(response)
}

RunLoop.current.run()
```

Writes to debug console output e.g:

```
2021-10-02 14:45:28.198648+0300 AlamofireExp1[4891:191952] [logging] volume does not support data protection, stripping SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_* flags
2021-10-02 14:45:28.199070+0300 AlamofireExp1[4891:191952] [logging] volume does not support data protection, stripping SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_* flags
2021-10-02 14:45:28.626982+0300 AlamofireExp1[4891:191952] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C1.1 54.159.86.231:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-10-02 14:45:28.627089+0300 AlamofireExp1[4891:191952] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C1.1 54.159.86.231:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
2021-10-02 14:45:28.756444+0300 AlamofireExp1[4891:191941] [logging] volume does not support data protection, stripping SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_* flags
2021-10-02 14:45:28.756749+0300 AlamofireExp1[4891:191941] [logging] volume does not support data protection, stripping SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_* flags
```

Question: How to suppress this garbage (for me) output to debug console?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't Alamofire logging, this is logging from the underlying OS. Unfortunately there's no good way to disable it. Technically you can add the `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` environment variable set to `disable` for your builds, but that disable all `OS` module functionality, including your own `OSLog`s and signposts, among other features, so it's not recommended.

Comment: Can you clarify re. the environment variable?  I tried that in Xcode as part of my target's run settings, but it has no effect…?